# Displaying graph in Java Application from .dot file

Tags: java, swing, graphviz, dot

I want to display a graph written in .dot file in my Java application as an image. Is there any library to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Graphviz ... Build the graphviz package from source to ensure it contains Java bindings.